# Trouble understanding "Fixed effects" and "Correlation in mixed effect models"

Tags: r, statistics, lm, lme4, mixed-models

I have an assignment in mixed effect models, but there is little to none information regarding the "lmer" output. The data used in the assignment regards two treatment types (treatment OTC and control CTL) on plant height.

This is the code used:

`mod_vivipara <- lmer(Value ~ Treatment + (1|Site), data = bistorta_vivipara)

summary(mod_vivipara)`

The picture is what the output looks like.

The code I used shows what I'm supposed to have, but I'm having trouble understanding what the output is telling me. I've tried searching for answers and have read articles on it - but I need it explained in an easier way. [The output from the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvuOP.png)

Comment: This is not the right place for a statistics lecture. Basically, the fixed effects tell you the parameters for the population mean. The random effects tell you how the individuals vary around the population mean. A normal distribution is assumed and in your example you have a random intercept (but no random slope), meaning that you only model site-specific variation around the intercept and not for the treatment effect. I suggest you get this book from a library: https://books.google.de/books/about/Mixed_Effects_Models_and_Extensions_in_E.html?id=vQUNprFZKHsC&redir_esc=y

Comment: I suggest you to submit your question on Cross Validated

Comment: When you submit your question to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), or now (in anticipation of it being migrated), it would be best to replace the link to the screenshot of the output with a textual version (i.e., cut and paste from the R console ...)

Answer (score 0):

The Formula tells you your model: Value is the response, Treatment is a fixed effect (with two levels-control and treatment), and you have a random intercept for each Site.

REML criterion is some convergence criterion for restricted maximum likelihood.

Scaled residuals are 5-number-summaries of the residuals, scaled (subtracted by mean and divided by sd).

Under random effects, the Intercept for each Site is drawn from a N(0, 0.2793) distribution. You also have the variance of the residuals.

You have the fixed effect estimates (standard `lm` output), and the correlation between B0 and B1.